# ngx-monaco-editor : unable to find loader.js file from node_modules

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, monaco-editor

I want to include ngx-monaco-editor in my project to create a calculator-like screen on the front-end which shows the text entered as the user clicks on the corresponding buttons.

I have installed ngx-monaco-editor (version 6.0.0) for the same.

The dependencies have been included in app.module.ts and I have added the glub to assets in the angular.json file.

app.component.hlml :

```
<ngx-monaco-editor [options]="editorOptions" [(ngModel)]="code"></ngx-monaco-editor>
```

app.component.ts :

```
editorOptions = {theme: 'vs-dark', language: 'javascript'};
code: string= 'function x() {\nconsole.log("Hello world!");\n}';
```

The editor is not getting rendered. I'm instead getting an error that my loader.js file is not getting found.

http://localhost:4200/assets/monaco/vs/loader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
@base-editor.js:65

The loader.js file is located at node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/assets/monaco/vs/loader.js and I'm able to navigate to it.

The error is occuring at base-editor.js, line 65. The location for this file is node_modules/ngx-monaco-editor/base-editor.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing the input configuration in angular.json enabled the files to be copied over to the dist folder.
Changing the output configuration allowed the loader.json file to be found.

Answer (score 2):

There is no asset folder in 10.0.0 but there is in version 9.0.0
I use it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`ngx-monaco-editor` requires `monaco-editor`

1. Install monaco-editor: `npm install monaco-editor`
2. Add a entry under `projects>architect>options>assets` in angular.json:

`{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/monaco-editor", "output": "assets/monaco-editor" }`

Comment: this helped in my case, thanks.